# Easiest way to generalize $\lim_{p \to \infty} [\theta a^{\frac{1}{p}} + (1 - \theta)b^{\frac{1}{p}}]^p = a^ \theta b^{1 - \theta}$

Tags: real-analysis

It is known that
$$\lim_{p \to \infty} [\theta a^{\frac{1}{p}} + (1 - \theta)b^{\frac{1}{p}}]^p = a^ \theta b^{1 - \theta}. \tag{1}$$
For $a, b > 0$, $\theta \in (0, 1)$.
What would be the easiest way to prove the following statement using $(1)$

$$\lim_{p \to \infty} [\theta_1 a_1^{\frac{1}{p}} + \theta_2 a_2^{\frac{1}{p}} + \ldots + \theta_n a_n^{\frac{1}{p}}]^p = a_1^{\theta_1} a_2^{\theta_2} \ldots a_n^{\theta_n},$$
where $\theta_k > 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \theta_k = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct method to prove the result is to apply L'Hospital rule. Let  $$y = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta_i a_i^{1/p}\right)^{p} \implies \ln(y) = \frac{\ln(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta_i a_i^{1/p})}{1/p}.$$
Now apply L'Hospital rule to arrive at
$$\lim_{p \to \infty} \ln(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta_i \ln(a_i).$$